# (Fluent) Nhibernate Map collection of objects from single table row with different column names per object C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Customer class that has a list of Address class as a property. The problem I am running into is when trying to map the Address class with Fluent Nhibernate when the source is a single record in a single database table.

My classes are as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContactName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressType Type { get; set; }
}
```

The database schema is as follows:

```
TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMER](
    [CUSTID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [FIRSTNAME] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [LASTNAME] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CONTACTNAME] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MAINADDRESS1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MAINADDRESS2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MAINCITY] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MAINSTATE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [MAINZIP] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MAINCOUNTRY] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SHIPADDRESS1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SHIPADDRESS2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SHIPCITY] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SHIPSTATE] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SHIPZIP] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [SHIPCOUNTRY] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EnglishAddress1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EnglishAddress2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EnglishCity] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EnglishState] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [EnglishZip] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [EnglishCountry] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
)
```

I would like to map each address in the single customer record to an individual Address Class in the list with a different address type.

Does anyone know how to properly do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best solution is to refactor your schema so that you have a seperate Address table.

But assuming you can't do that, you could map the Address class as a component to separate MainAddress, ShipAddress and EnglishAddress properties and then simply expose them via the list for iteration.

```
public class Customer
{
    // other properties

    protected virtual Address MainAddress { get; set; }
    protected virtual Address ShipAddress { get; set; }
    protected virtual Address EnglishAddress { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<Address> _addresses = null;
    public virtual IEnumerable<Address> Addresses
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (_addresses == null)
            {
                MainAddress.AddressType = AddressType.Main;
                ShipAddress.AddressType = AddressType.Ship;                                     
                EnglishAddress.AddressType = AddressType.English;
               _addresses = new[] { MainAddress, ShipAddress, EnglishAddress };
            }
            return _addresses;
        }
    }
}
```

Then map as follows

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
     public CustomerMap()
     {
         // map customer properties

         Component(Reveal.Member<Customer>("MainAddress"), m =>
         {
             m.Map(x => x.Address1, "MainAddress1");
             m.Map(x => x.Address2, "MainAddress2");
             // other address properties
         };

         Component(Reveal.Member<Customer>("ShipAddress"), m =>
         {
             m.Map(x => x.Address1, "ShipAddress1");
             m.Map(x => x.Address2, "ShipAddress2");
             // other address properties
         };

         // same for english address
    }
}
```

You won't be able to add additional addresses, but you couldn't really add them with your schema as it is anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I can't change the schema otherwise I would. I will add the 3 properties for each object.

Thank you for your help